# Proper Way To do Similar Actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails Model and Controller that correspond to Projects. Each Project has multiple statuses. Let's say the status can be proposal, approved, archived.

In my controller I have an index action. However, in my views throughout the app I want to link to proposal, approved and archived projects and only display those.

I could create actions such as approve, propose, archive, etc and have those get only those that match.

The other thing I was considering is with each link pass in a variable into params that would then dictate what the index action did.

Which of these two is the proper way and/or am I missing something in rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I definitely prefer the option of the variable set in the params. It is DRY'er this way and adding a new status would be almost effortless. To implement it I would use the following code:

```
# routes.rb

match 'projects/:filter' => 'projects#filter', :constraints => { :filter => /^approved$|^archived$|^proposal$/}

# ProjectsController.rb

  def filter
    @projects = Project.where(:status => params[:filter])
  end
```

This way, if you add more statuses all you have to do is to allow the filtering in the routes definition.

Comment: @apneadiving and Emrah could I have worded it better in some way?

Comment: @Erez, I assume it'd be possible to do a simple `if !filter Project.all else Project.where....` as well?

Comment: You could route to projects#index instead of projects#filter and do
`if params[:filter]
  @projects = Project.where(:status => params[:filter])
 else
  @projects = Project.all
end`